# Isomorphic ReactJS or Web Components(Polymer) Which one to be followed by a developer?

Tags: reactjs, polymer, web-component, isomorphic-javascript

In these years we are seeing multiple technologies on disposal for web development like:

**Isomorphic React:**

It provides a common code base shared among client and server.

**Web Components :**

Polymer.js shows the way of creating native element for the browser.

Both of these technologies are going in opposite direction.Which one a web developer should follow?Any suggestions/comments are welcome here.

Comment: Just learn Haskell instead.

Comment: YUI might make a comeback

Answer (score 6, accepted):

React and Web Components are similar, but not the same. What's great about Web Components (or the idea at least, we're not quite there yet) is that you're supposed to be able to extend HTML with custom elements. The browser doesn't give you a `<datepicker>` element? Throw in a Web Component that implements it! You don't have to worry about how it implements it, you just import it and then you can use it. Turns out that it has poor accessibility or poor browser support? Someone else will surely have created something better.

A big issue with Web Components currently though is that they add global names. So if there will ever be a de facto Web Components registry like NPM for Node, you will have a race for the best names. But with NPM that's not a huge issue, because you can name the variable what you want, like `var Promise = require('bluebird');`. It tells you what it does. But a Web Component named `blue-bird` would be terrible, since you won't have any idea what that does when reading the markup that uses it. So if that doesn't get fixed before Web Components are final, we'll end up with long, prefixed, wierd names to avoid name clashes.

Web Components are meant to be smallish components that are quite general. Things like a date picker, a select list with auto complete, a map element, etc. They are not meant to solve how you structure your application, but instead how we can reuse common elements between sites. So you might see custom elements like `<date-picker>` but you won't see an `index.html` with just `<body><my-app></my-app></body>` where `my-app` is a Web Component for your specific app. Well, maybe you'll see it, but that's not really the purpose of Web Components and it doesn't give you a lot of tools to do it.

React on the other hand is all about how you structure your application, and passing data between your components. You can pass plain Javascript objects as properties to React components, but the only thing you can pass as an attribute to a Web Component is a string. Which works for simple stuff, but not for your entire application.

They are not mutually exclusive since you'll probably see a lot of people using Web Components inside their React applications. But if you see anyone creating a Web Component that depends on React, please feel free to shout at them. Web Components are supposed to be isolated and reusable, and including a big library/framework like React inside one is an anti-pattern.

Comment: So it means the react component can use HTML Imports,Shadow DOM,tempating and custom elements!!!

Comment: React can use Web Components just like most other frameworks will be able to. React used to have a whitelist of builtin HTML elements. That whitelist is removed now, so they will treat custom elements just like any other element. You probably won't use HTML Imports, templating and custom elements inside your React app though, because React solves those problems in other ways. But you can certainly use a Web Component in your React application that uses those technologies.

Comment: It mean only custom elements can be useful inside React.But we can create custom elements directly in React, right?

Comment: You can use a custom element inside a React component, but you won't create/write them inside the React application. React already has its own concept of components (which are better than custom elements in a lot of ways), so the only thing to gain is to be able to take an isolated third party Web Component and use that inside your React app. If you use React, you won't create Web Components/custom elements for that app, you'll just create React components.

Comment: Thanks for your views.One more thing i wanted to know from you, which one of the technology stack you will suggest for a web application development.

Comment: I can't really recommend Web Components as a way to create a full blown application, because it's not really meant for it. If you want, you can use Polymer which is a framework on top of Web Components. Polymer also adds more functionality and features on top of it which will never be added to "vanilla" Web Components. So it's not like "If I use Polymer today, I can throw out Polymer tomorrow when Web Components are implemented in all browsers". I haven't used Polymer a lot, so I can't really judge it, but I've used React a lot and really enjoy working with it.